# Why tolist takes too long for only 1 item?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I make a stored procedure call to SQL Server, and I try to get only 1 item. The db returns instantly, however it runs very slow when I try to use `ToList()`

```
public partial class Product: BaseEntity, ISlugSupported
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }       
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public bool InStock { get; set; }
    public int StockQuantity { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductCostInUSD { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductCostInUSDOldPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductCostInPound { get; set; }       
    public decimal ProductCostInEuro { get; set; }     
    public decimal ProductCostInVND { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; }
    public decimal ExchangeRateUSD { get; set; }     
    public decimal ExchangeRateEuro { get; set; }    
    public decimal ExchangeRatePound { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public string Createdby { get; set; }

    public int Status { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }        
}
```

Stored procedure method:

```
    public class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private DbSet<T> _entities;

        public EFRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            this._context = context;            
        }

        public IQueryable<T> ExecuteStoredProcedureList(string commandText, params object[] parameters) 
        {
            return _context.Set<T>().FromSql(commandText, parameters);           
        }
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<Product>()
           .ToTable("Product")
           .Ignore(p => p.ProductFinalCost);
    }
}
```

[image]

Calling the stored procedure:

```
 var query = _productRepository.ExecuteStoredProcedureList("dbo.[SearchProducts] " +
                  "@Keywords, @PageIndex,@PageSize,@SortBy,@FromDate, @ToDate,@Sku,@CreateBy,@CategoryIds,@OrderIds,@ShowPublished,@Discontinued,@Discount,@LoadFilterableSpecificationAttributeOptionIds, @FilterableSpecificationAttributeOptionIds OUTPUT,@PriceMin,@PriceMax,@ShowExpiredProduct,@FilterableBrands OUTPUT,@TotalRecords OUTPUT,@FilteredSpecs, @FilteredBrands,@LoadSimple,@TrungvangPick",
                  pKeywords,
                  pPageIndex,
                  pPageSize,
                  pSortBy,
                  pFromDate,
                  pToDate,
                  pSku,
                  pCreatedBy,
                  pCategoryIds,
                   pOrderIds,
                  pShowPublished,
                   pDiscontinued,
                   pDiscount,                      
                  pLoadFilterableSpecificationAttributeOptionIds,
                  pFilterableSpecificationAttributeOptionIds,
                  pPriceMin,
                  pPriceMax,
                  pShowExpiredProduct,
                  pFilterableBrands,
                  pTotalRecords,
                  pFilteredSpecs,
                  pFilteredBrands,
                  pLoadSimple,
                  pTrungvangPick
                 );

var result = query.ToList();

int totalRecords = pTotalRecords.Value != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt32(pTotalRecords.Value) : 0;
```

The stored procedure in SQL Server returns instantly, so this is not a stored procedure problem (tested directly to run on the database).

As you can see from the point var results to the next command, it takes up to 467ms for only 1 simple item `ProductSimple` which only contains a few numeric fields, and I tried to move the debug point back and forth to check the speed, it still maintains at the same amount of time.

On the other project, this `ToList()` converts very fast for the same item structure. What could be the possible wrong things that I make ?

[image]

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.2.4 and EF Core 2.2.4

Comment: How should we know if you don't post your linq code :P Also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: ``.ToList()`` sends query to db

Comment: Most likely, `query` is an IQueryable.  This means that the actual query execution is deferred and runs when you call ".ToList".

Comment: However as you did not provide your axctual query, it´s impossible for us to guess why it takes "so long".

Comment: Yea, but we don't know what the queryable is like, w/o the linq/lambda syntax on it. It could be due to client sided evaluations (user should see warning in the logs by default settings) or something else which forces it to be evaluated locally

Comment: Apart from this don´t use your debugger to measure the time between two statements. Chances are high there´s some debugger-internals happening which leads to whrong numbers.

Comment: @Grax it's true, it's IQueryable but don't know why it's take that long for 1 item collection

Comment: @namvo you haven't even posted that query. What does it do and what does the *stored procedure* do? It's not `ToList()` that's slow. The queries are definitely different. An inefficient query will always be slow.

Comment: We don't see the stored proc either. Lot of reasons, bad/missing index, using something that prevents your db engine from using the index etc.

Comment: There is probably a issue with the generated sql query from your linq statement which takes to long to complete. As stated before once you do a ToList() or First() last() etc.. you query gets executed. For investigating you can add the following in your DbContext constructor.

Database.Log = (query) => { Debug.WriteLine(query); }; Which vents the generated sql query to you VS Debug output.

Answer (score 0):

The query does not return immediately.  The query does not actually execute until the .ToList call.

How long the query takes to return depends on the time to connect to your database as well as the efficiency of the query.